# Docker Nginx not pointing to index html

Tags: html, reactjs, docker, nginx

I have react with vite, Im trying to start it on docker image

nginx.conf

```
events {
    # Event-driven configuration
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Include server configurations
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # Further http configurations
}
```

default.conf

```
server {
    # Listen on port 80 for incoming connections
    listen 80;

    # Define the root directory where your files are located
    # This should be the path to your built React application
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Specify the file to serve as index
    index index.html;

    # Handle Single Page Application (SPA) routing:
    # Attempt to serve any requested file or route, fall back to index.html if not found
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Custom error pages (optional)
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```

Docker section of nginx

FROM nginx:alpine

```
# Step 6: Copy build artifacts from the 'build' stage to the Nginx directory
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/build
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Step 7: Expose port 80 for Nginx
EXPOSE 80

# Step 8: Start Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

console after run:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2024:13:47:46 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2024:13:47:47 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2024:13:47:47 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2024:13:47:48 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2024:13:48:19 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

chrome page:

[image]

and inside he docker container:

```
/ # ls -ltr /etc/nginx/
total 36
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           664 Oct 24 16:48 uwsgi_params
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           636 Oct 24 16:48 scgi_params
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          5349 Oct 24 16:48 mime.types
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1007 Oct 24 16:48 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1077 Oct 24 16:48 fastcgi.conf
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Dec 20 20:13 modules -> /usr/lib/nginx/modules
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           262 Jan  6 13:46 nginx.conf
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan  6 13:47 conf.d
/ # ls -ltr /etc/nginx/conf.d/
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           655 Jan  6 13:53 default.conf
/ # ls -ltr /usr/share/nginx/html/build/*index*
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           398 Jan  6 13:37 /usr/share/nginx/html/build/index.html
/ #
```

how can I majke it show the App.tsx file

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>^M
<html lang="en">^M
  <head>^M
    <meta name="monetag" content="5a02f84c329734f784dc0af09b7ae775">^M
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />^M
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../favicon192.png" />^M
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />^M
    <title>Vite + React + TS 2</title>^M
  </head>^M
  <body>^M
    <div id="root"></div>^M
  </body>^M
</html>^M
```

Comment: It looks like you're copying the built content into a `build` subdirectory.  Does `http://.../build/` show your application?

Comment: (Your Nginx configuration otherwise looks like the defaults, and you probably don't need the custom `*.conf` files.)